# How should I write my C code to have the resulting assembly use extra dsll32 and dsra32 instructions?

Tags: c, mips, codewarrior, metrowerks

I'm decompiling a PS2 game that was shipped as a debug build. I've gotten as far as decompiling enough to be able compile an ELF file using the compiler that was originally used (Metrowerks CodeWarrior).

Now I'm doing comparisons between the disassembly of the original ELF file and the disassembly of the one I compiled. There's one recurring pattern that the original assembly has that mine doesn't: regular shifting using the dsll32 and dsra32 instructions.

Original assembly:

```
dsll32  v1,s1,16
dsra32  v1,v1,16
subu    v1,$0,v1
dsll32  v1,v1,16
dsra32  v1,v1,16
dsll32  s1,v1,16
dsra32  s1,s1,16
```

This was decompiled to the following C code:

```
d1 = -d1;
```

And was compiled to the following assembly:

```
subu    v1,$0,s1
dsll32  s1,v1,16
dsra32  s1,s1,16
```

Notice that one pair of shifting instructions is missing. So far, I've failed to replicate this. I've tried adding various casts, changing it to `d1 = 0 - d1`, I was suggested to add a 64-bit cast, but nothing achieves the desired result.

Here's another example:

Original assembly:

```
lh      v0,80(sp)
dsll32  v1,v0,16
dsra32  v1,v1,16
lw      v0,128(sp)
lb      v0,0(v0)
dsll32  v0,v0,24
dsra32  v0,v0,24
dsll32  v0,v0,16
dsra32  v0,v0,16
addu    v0,v1,v0
dsll32  v0,v0,16
dsra32  v0,v0,16
dsll32  s3,v0,16
dsra32  s3,s3,16
```

C code:

```
x = xposi + sprdat->xoff;
```

Compiled to:

```
lh      v1,80(sp)
lw      v0,128(sp)
lb      v0,0(v0)
dsll32  v0,v0,24
dsra32  v0,v0,24
addu    v0,v1,v0
dsll32  s3,v0,16
dsra32  s3,s3,16
```

Does anyone have any idea what C code would be responsible for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TL;DR: Don't worry things are fine.

1. You're decompiling a *debug* version. So, optimization is [probably] turned off.
2. The original assembly looks like unoptimized code.
3. The decompiled code is `d1 = -d1;`
4. The resultant assembly of your recompiled code is *optimized* with an additional factor (see below).
5. On an x86, this would produce a *single* instruction. If `d1` were in (e.g.) `%ecx`, the assembly would be: `neg %ecx`
6. On architectures that don't have that (e.g. `mips`), we subtract the value from 0.

The following is a bit of a rough explanation.

---

The C [decompiled] variable is `d1`. It resides in MIPS register `s1`. The code uses a temporary variable (call it `tmp`) that resides in MIPS register `v1`

To avoid confusion [possibly just mine :-)] between the arbitrary name assigned by the decompiler `d1`, let's rename this as `mydata`.

In the original assembly, the first two instructions are converting a 16 bit integer into a 32 bit integer:

```
dsll32  v1,s1,16            # move 16 bit int's sign bit into bit 31
dsra32  v1,v1,16            # shift back with sign extension
```

*Logical* right shift would shift zeroes in from the left.

However ...

*Arithmetic* right shift will shift bit 31 into the number from the left side.

This is common trick for a number of architectures that *don't* have (as x86 *does*) special CISC instructions for moving a 16 bit number into a 32 bit register with automatic sign extension (e.g. `movswl`), either from memory or another register.

For example, a -1 in a `short` would have a bit pattern of 0xFFFF (i.e. 0x0000FFFF). We are converting this to 32 bits (i.e. 0xFFFFFFFF)

This uses an extra `tmp` variable that is put in register `v1`. The `tmp` is probably [implicitly] defined as:

```
int tmp;
```

This all implies that `mydata` (which resides in register `s1`) was defined as a 16 bit integer:

```
short mydata;
```

Although x86 has word size arithmetic instructions that operate directly on 16 bits (e.g. `subw`), MIPS only has 32 bit arithmetic register-to-register instructions (the exception is the `addi` which sign extends the immediate operand).

Now, to actually negate the number, we subtract it from zero:

```
subu    v1,$0,v1                # perform negation
```

The equivalent C code is:

```
tmp = 0 - tmp;
```

The next two instructions put the sign bit from the 32 bit `tmp` into the sign bit of a 16 bit number:

```
dsll32  v1,v1,16                # put sign bit from 16 bit part into bit 31
dsra32  v1,v1,16                # shift back to get sign bit for 16 bit number
```

The remaining two instructions are doing a similar [and unnecessary] conversion to get the final 16 bit value for `mydata`:

```
dsll32  s1,v1,16                # mydata = tmp << 16;
dsra32  s1,s1,16                # mydata = mydata >> 16;
```

---

The rebuilt assembly already assumes that `s1` has been sign extended to 32 bits (in prior instructions). So, the first two instructions of the original assembly aren't needed:

```
# assume s1 has _already_ been sign extended to 32 bits here in _prior_
# instructions
subu    v1,$0,s1

# move sign bit from 32 bits back to 16 bits
dsll32  s1,v1,16
dsra32  s1,s1,16
```

And, the extra unnecessary final two instructions are elided.

---

To summarize: The recompiled code does exactly what the original code does, but is optimized to do it in fewer instructions.

The second example is doing much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot of sense. However, I do suspect there's something more going on, because I do compile without optimisations. I took another look at my compiler's options, but there's nothing there that's relevant.

Comment: According to the documentation, `lh` and `lb` already sign-extend the value, so there's definitely something more going on.